# ¿Cómo separar varios Selects? Se juntan

Tags: html, css

llevo un rato tratando de encontrarle la solución a mi problema pero no entiendo el porque sucede.

Tengo 3 selects en un formulario y se juntan, no tienen un margen pero tampoco logro darcelos en el css

[image: Cómo se ve en la imagen, estos 3 estan juntos y quiero seguir el diseño de mi proyecto]

```
select {
 width: 48%;
 height: 52px;
}
```

Con ese código logre darles el tamaño que quería pero no logro la separación.

```
input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.input-48{
 width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
 width: 100%;
}

.input-dif{
 margin-left: 4%;
 width: 48%;
}

.input-dif2{
 margin-left: 52%;
 width: 48%;
}
```

Con el código anterior hice el diseño de todos los demás campos.

Soy bastante novato en esto de las páginas web..

Comment: Realmente eso podría tener **N** soluciones.:
---
1. Usar CSS Grid Layout.
2. Usar DIvs para poner allí cada Select.
3. Usar Positión: Absolute.
4. Usar Flexbox.
5. Usar Margin y Padding
6. y tal vez muchas mas...

Answer (score 3):

Es muy sencillo, simplemente añádele a la clase select un `margin-left: 4%;` como hiciste con los inputs. Así:

```css
select{
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 4%; /*esto es lo que necesitas añadirle al select*/
}

/*=============================================
===============================================
===============================================
LO SIGUIENTE LO PUEDES IGNORAR ES PARA QUE SE 
PAREZCA UN POCO A LA IMAGEN DE EJEMPLO
===============================================
===============================================
=============================================*/



*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/1600/1000?image=1044');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form{
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 35em;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: O directamente le pone el class .input-dif a los selects (ya que comparten las mismas características)

Answer (score 1):

Pon Un `<br>` después de cada `<input />` en El HTML eso separará los input.

Comment: Gracias, pero esa no es la solución, ya lo había probado anteriormente.

Comment: Comparte el Html y css juntos para ayudarte mejor Porf favor :)

Comment: @MatiasGamalier, el usuario Jose011 tiene razón, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta e incluir el código HTML. **Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)**. Saludos.

Comment: @Jose011 gracias por tu aporte y te comparto: Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Saludos.

Comment: O muchas gracias! @MauricioAriasOlave Por la informacion , saludos!

Comment: No te desanimes por el punto en contra, suele pasar bastante al principio debido a que las respuestas que puedan ser testeadas con el snippet de SO son mejor recibidas, o que el OP no haya formulado bien su pregunta y se haga una respuesta y diversas cosas así.

Answer (score 0):

podrías añadir un simple separador CSS, aunque este método es una solución para "salir del paso" te puede servir.

1. Crear una clase CSS con estos datos:

> .separador {    padding-left: 3px; }

Puedes usar margin-left también, revisa el manual de CSS por si encuentras otra opción que te pueda servir. :)

[Manual para CSS.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

2. Entre los select, puedes crear un "div" con class="separador"